# Moving w2016 image from ESXi to KVM gives message "No Bootable Device"

Tags: vmware-esxi, kvm-virtualization, windows-server-2016, convert

I'm trying to move a windows server 2016 image from ESXi to KVM, but I'm receiving the error "No Bootable Devices" when I try to boot it.

Here's the output of the command "virt-filesystems -a  ~/VM.qcow2 --all --long --uuid -h"

```
Name      Type       VFS  Label    MBR Size Parent   UUID
/dev/sda1 filesystem ntfs Recovery -   499M -        CCCEA1FFCEA1E246
/dev/sda2 filesystem vfat -        -   95M  -        AEA2-DC85
/dev/sda4 filesystem ntfs -        -   49G  -        903EA5533EA53360
/dev/sda1 partition  -    -        -   499M /dev/sda -
/dev/sda2 partition  -    -        -   99M  /dev/sda -
/dev/sda3 partition  -    -        -   16M  /dev/sda -
/dev/sda4 partition  -    -        -   49G  /dev/sda -
/dev/sda5 partition  -    -        -   256K /dev/sda -
/dev/sda  device     -    -        -   50G  -        -
```

Here's an excerpt from the XML for the VM:

```
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/data/A-DMZ-New.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='sda' bus='sata'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='qemu-xhci' ports='15'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x02' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='sata' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1f' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pcie-root'/>
    <controller type='pci' index='1' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='1' port='0x10'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='2' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='2' port='0x11'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='3' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='3' port='0x12'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='4' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='4' port='0x13'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x3'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:22:4a:ce'/>
      <source bridge='br1'/>
      <model type='e1000e'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target type='isa-serial' port='0'>
        <model name='isa-serial'/>
      </target>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='spice' autoport='yes'>
      <listen type='address'/>
```

Comment: How have you convert vmdk to qcow2 (what tool)?

Comment: I used qemu-img.

Comment: check the bus type in xml of the VM. Try to change it to bus=virtio

Comment: I've added the XML to the question.  Can you please let me know where I make the suggested edit?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/advanced-troubleshooting-boot-problems

Answer (score 1):

Try to change bus type to *virtio* and target dev to *vda* here:

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
  <source file='/data/A-DMZ-New.qcow2'/>
  <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
  <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
</disk>
```

Comment: it gives me an error: unsupported configuration: virtio disk cannot have an address of type 'drive'

Comment: I edited it to:
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/data/A-DMZ.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <boot order='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0c' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>

Comment: But it's still not working.  Same error as before.